# Concatenating fields and text in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have a sheet like the sample image provided below:

[image]

I want to dynamically reference the NameField in my message column. The message column is used for sending customised messages to customers. As I have over 3000 names, how do I dynamically do this?

Answer (score 0):

The link below answers the question
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Tv4d-Z2umjo;context-place=starred